# Some users facing issues changing app language in Android app

Tags: android, configuration, localization, resources, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an Android application that allows users to switch between English and other languages (Arabic & French). I have a LocaleHelper class that manages language settings using SharedPreferences. However, some users are reporting difficulty changing the app language.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleHelper {

  private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

  public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String language = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, language);
  }

  public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
  }

  private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
  }

  private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
  }

  private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
  }
}
```

this is the LocalHelper class.

```
 public void changeLanguage() {

        final Welcome_Activity.Item[] items = {new Welcome_Activity.Item("  English", R.drawable.ukicon), new Welcome_Activity.Item("عربي  ", R.drawable.saudiicon), new Welcome_Activity.Item("  Français", R.drawable.frenchicon),};

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Welcome_Activity.Item>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items) {
            @NonNull
            @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                //Use super class to create the View
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT + Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                tv.setTextSize(23);
                //tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                //Put the image on the TextView
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                return v;
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Language").setAdapter(adapter, (dialog, which) -> {
            if (which == 0) {
                updateViews("en");
                recreate();
            } else if (which == 1) {
                updateViews("ar");
                recreate();
            } else if (which == 2) {
                updateViews("fr");
                recreate();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();


    }

 private void updateViews(String languageCode) {
        Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, languageCode);
        context.getResources();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

this code is in mainactivity.

Comment: please share a logcat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.